# How can I have a doctype file for each page and a title for each page?

Tags: php, html, title, doctype

My crazy web teacher requires a doctype.php file to be in each of my webpages to avoid repetition, like this:

```
<?php include 'doctype.php'; ?>
```

However, I also need a different title for each page.

```
<head>
    <title>Activities at Pacific Trails Resort</title>
</head>
```

This doesn't pass in http://validator.w3.org/. How do I include the doctype and the title?

Comment: your web teacher is not crazy. the specs require it

Comment: if used a template system or cms. you would only ever add it once to one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your doctype.php page add the following:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

(The trailing empty line is intentional, you will need to ensure it exists in the doctype.php file.)

In each of the other pages, they should look something like:

```
<?php include 'doctype.php'; ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Activities at Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Then when you visit each page, the output will be something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Activities at Pacific Trails Resort</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the include line is longer than that which it includes

Comment: Yes but if it changes you don't need to change it on every page, which is the point, you only have to update it once.

Answer (score 0):

you could always make yourself a little function for the start of your page and pass the title as a variable. You would put the function in your config.php and then all you have to do is require "config.php" and start your page with startPage("your title").

```
function startPage($title)
{
    echo<<<END
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>$title</title>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/admin.css' type='text/css'>
        </head>
END;
}
```

ETA: I've gotten 2 down-votes for this but no explanation why. It might be breaking php's style guidelines because I'm echoing html? Not sure?